# PHP array_filter outputs sometimes index number

Tags: php, json, array-filter

I encountered some strange error with array_filter.

My json data looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "item": "book",
            "date": "9.10."
        },
        {
            "item": "apple",
            "date": "10.10."
        },
        {
            "item": "pen",
            "date": "11.10."
        }
    ]
}
```

I can remove some objects with this code:

```
$days_arr = array('9.10.','10.10.');
    $result['data'] = array_filter($my_var['data'], function($v) use ($days_arr)
      {
        return in_array($v['date'], $days_arr);
        });
        return json_encode($result);
```

Which removes the objects containing a date = 9.10. and 10.10.
But the problem: as soon as I use `$days_arr = array('9.10.','11.10.');`

My output is this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "item": "book",
            "date": "9.10."
        },
        "1": {
            "item": "pen",
            "date": "11.10"
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, some very strange error happens, the json is completely wrong formatted.
9.10. and 10.10. works, 10.10. and 11.10. destroys the output.

Who can help?

Comment: I doubt it actually happens with your given example: https://eval.in/877329 that being said if you do end up with indices 0,2 remaining (notice the gap) then the equivalent JSON structure will be an object and not an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincidentally, your first example results in consecutive indexes starting at 0, 0 and 1 so `json_encode()` encodes them as dynamically assigned.  The second example yields indexes 0 and 2 so it uses the hard coded values.  Use `array_values()` to re-index:

```
$result['data'] = array_values($result['data']);
return json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of important things:

- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will preserve the keys of the elements that pass the filter
- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will preserve array keys in the output "if the keys are not a continuous numeric sequence starting from 0"

So when your `$result` array contains array keys `0` and `1`, they are skipped in the JSON output. When it contains array keys `0` and `2` (as in your second example), they'll be preserved.

You can avoid your problem by removing the keys in the call to `json_encode`:

```
return json_encode(array_values($result));
```

This will keep the output in the same format as the input. See https://eval.in/877330